# Enumerate and numbering

Tags: lists, numbering, enumerate, enumitem

We are using the enumerate in the following form

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\bfseries${\textbf{{C}}}_\arabic*$.]

\item 

\end{enumerate}
```

Which produces out-put as C_1, C_2, ...

But we want the out-put as C_8, C_9, ...

How can we do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I have deleted my answer since Guido beat me to it. But you can improve your `label` by deleting spurious commands and braces. With the `step` option as mentioned by Guido, you can write `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=$\textbf{C}_\arabic*$.,start=8]`.

Answer (score 8):

to continue the numbering from a previous list you can add `resume` in the options. To set the starting number add the option `start=<integer>` (see section 3.4 of the `enumitem` manual, `texdoc enumitem`)